# Gradle Run MainClass from external dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have two gradle-configured projects, projectA and projectB.  ProjectA is a spring boot project with two main classes, one run when running projectA directly, another run when running projectB (see gradle file below).  ProjectA is exported as a JAR which is declared as a dependency of projectB.  ProjectB specifies as its main class a class from projectA.jar:

```
//ProjectB's build.gradle


apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.projectA.api.MainClassToBeRunInProjectB'

/**
 * `verify` task, `run` task to be exact
 */
task verify(dependsOn:run)

dependencies{
    compile (group:'com.projectA.api',name:'api-ProjectA-jar',version:'1.0.0')
}

//Download artifacts
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.projectJarLocations.local/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

When running the verify step in projectB, the build fails as follows:

```
acidnbass:projectB acidnbass$ gradle clean verify

> Task :run
Error: Could not find or load main class com.projectA.api.MainClassToBeRunInProjectB


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Why can't I run the main class from projectA?  Is there extra config needed to run a main class from an external source?

Answer (score 1):

its possible by setting up a task like this:

```
task runApp(dependsOn: configurations.compileClasspath, type: JavaExec) {
    group = "app"
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.projectA.api.MainClassToBeRunInProjectB'
}
```

and by adding a dependency as an implementation

```
dependencies{
    implementation('com.projectA.api:api-ProjectA-jar:1.0.0')
}
```